# Is it possible to enable kerberos on OS X 10.9 without joining the Active Directory domain?

Tags: macos, domain, kerberos

I would like to be able to take advantage of Kerberos without having to join my machine to the domain.

Why? Because this is a personal machine and we are not allowed to join them the corporate domain (nor we can).

Comment: OS X sets up KDC automagically and uses it internally whether you join a domain or not. What specifically are you trying to do? Kerberos is there to use unless your installation has disabled it or configured it to not work in some manner.

Comment: Is there a way to tell OS X which user/password to user for kerberos *if* it happens for you not to have the same user or password on your local machine?

Comment: @bmike so kerberos client is not configured automatically, it cannot be as it doesn't know your domain. I was able to obtain a ticket from the command line and to authenticate using CURL. The ticket is visible in Ticket Viewer but no browser is using it. As soon I have a solution I will update, any hints would be more than welcomed.

Comment: I took your "take advantage of kerberos without joining a domain" as you were in stand alone mode only. Clearly, if you need to access the Authentication Server that is remote if you want to get a ticket from that server for use on the local host. I think you need OS X server to have a minimal KDC set up, so my "automagically" isn't going to help on non server.app Macs. Do post your setup once you have something worked out. I'm curious how many realms you have set up and what specific client setup works in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my partial success so far. I was able to setup Kerberos authentication but only on Firefox and Google Chrome, on Safari it doesn't work and it seems to be impossible to make it work without really joining the domain.

### OS X Kerberos Setup

```
>kinit username@EXAMPLE.COM

>klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: user@EXAMPLE.COM
Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
06/05/14 11:36:00  06/05/14 21:36:06  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 07/05/14 11:36:00
```

Now you can use `/System/Library/CoreServices/Ticket Viewer.app` to view the ticket, or to renew it when it expires.

### CURL

```
 curl -v --negotiate -u : -b ~/cookiejar.txt -c ~/cookiejar.txt --output /dev/null http://example.com
```

### Firefox

go to `about:config` and configure `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris: .example.com`

### Chrome

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthServerWhitelist "*.example.com"
defaults write com.google.Chrome AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist "*.example.com"
```

### Safari [broken!]

Base on https://www.pingidentity.com/support/solutions/index.cfm/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM#safari it seems that Safari will use SPNEGO only when it is joined into the domain. Otherwise it will only try NTLM which is probably disabled as being insecure.

**Any contributions are more than welcomed!**